# How to decrease the size of input-group-addon Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
   <div class="time input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4">Start Time
          </span>
        <timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime" required></timepicker></div>
```

How to decrease the height of input-group-addon icon?
It must be equal to the size of input timer box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your related code

Comment: what do you mean by related code? I have pasted the related code.

Comment: I mean the styles you have added. If you use only bootstrap css then you have to customize the `input-group-addon` class with fixed height like input field and align it.

Comment: I have not used any styles. I'm able to declare the height of addon in css but I'm only able to increase the height. Unable to decrease it. It seems to be like fixed.

Comment: It gets inherited to the size of input. In my case to the size of timepicker.

Comment: I think you use bootstrap 3 version, where the `.input-group` class has `display: table` and the childrens has `display: table-cell` thats why the height is not working. I am giving a sample with custom css in the answer, hope you will get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet,

```css
.form-control.timepicker {
  height: 100px; /* Sample height */
}
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.input-group-addon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Miraz Chowdry.

Answer (score 2):

```
         .input-group.check {
         position: relative;
         padding-left: 125px;
         }
         .input-group-addon.check2 {
         position: absolute;
         top: 59%;
         left: 0;
         transform: translateY(-50%);
         width: 125px !important;
         height: 40px;
         display: block;
         padding-top: 12px;
         }
```

I just modified the above the code as per my requirement and it helped.
Thanks.[image]